# Disable the access of the product Individually by product url, but product should be listed in serach

Tags: php, magento-1.9

In my site I need to show product detail in popup. I have done that, but there is a problem product url is also open in browser. I need to disable all the product url open in browser for all product without sat the product Not Visible Individually.

Comment: Can you post your code for what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the product to be SEARCH ONLY - as per your question, then the product will be simply that.  The code you implement for the popup should not use this flag when querying your product collection (i.e. don't apply a visibility filter) and then you can still get the data out into your popup.